# sort table with timestamp field without considering time of day

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in Mysql (firstname,lastname,data1,data2,...) that one field name is **MYDATE** and  type of this field is `timestamp`.  In this field, the date saved  as (yyyy-mm-dd mm:ss:ms), and there are many records of this table.

I want write a **select query** that sort this table with (yyyy-mm-dd) and without considering (mm:ss:ms).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
ORDER BY date(mydate)
```

but it will cause fullscan.

Answer (score 3):

Just cast it to a date in your order by clause:

```
SELECT columns
FROM some_table
ORDER BY CAST(mydate AS date);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select columns
from table_name
order by date_format(date_column, '%Y-%m-%d')
```